# Редактирование DataGridView

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagridview

Не могу отредактировать ячейки из DataGridView хотя ReadOnly = False;
Заполняю грид так :

класс для работы с базой данных

```
  public ArrayList selectCustomers()
    {
        ArrayList ollCustomers = new ArrayList();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from customers order by customer_Name", conn);
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    foreach (DbDataRecord result in reader)
                    {
                        ollCustomers.Add(result);

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return ollCustomers;
    }
```

на форме с гридом :

```
    ArrayList customers = dal.selectCustomers();
    dgv_customers.DataSource = customers;
```

Подскажите что не так. спасибо

Comment: `DbDataRecord` реализует только read-only индексатор. Создайте модель данных и записывайте значения из ридера в неё. Также используйте вместо `ArrayList` типизированный `List<T>`, где `T` - ваша модель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вариант для изменения текста в каждой ячейки :

```
    private void dgv_customers_CellContentClick(object sender,DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            dgv_customers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
    }
```

но когда нажимаю Enter выскакивает - исключение в  datagrid . метод не поддерживается.